# batch moving files (prestashop)

Tags: javascript, php, image, prestashop, batch-processing

in prestashop, image subfolders structure is like 123.jpg -> 1/2/3/p.jpg.

I need a script, or code, or something to distribute files 001.jpg - 123.jpg to appropriate subfolders. (0/0/1/p.jpg ... 1/2/3/p.jpg)

The reason is I dont like the way prestashop optimazes images, I want to do it my way and I keep images in one parent folder. When optimized, I want to distribute them to aproprite subfolders.

I prefer desktop/php version of script, maybe something like gulp/grunt works. I really apreciate any help... :-)

Comment: Folder structure is p/1/2/3.jpg. I don't think it is ready made solution. If you have a folder with all the images, like 123.jpg, 124.jpg, etc. you will need a script which loops through all the files and forms a path (p/1/2/) from its name (123.jpg) and copies the image (as 3.jpg).

Comment: Yes, that is the script I am looking for.... :-) Sounds like I need to loop with WHILE or so, then decompose those numbers in string, somehow concatenate them with /s to create path to subfolder...